# Flex 3 browserManager.fragment question

Tags: apache-flex

I need some help. I've got a Flex 3 website. I can't read the var o below.

If I have a URL that looks like this:

http://mysite.html#view=my-important-stuff

What will o equal?

```
private function parseUrl(e:BrowserChangeEvent = null):void {

  var o:Object = URLUtil.stringToObject(browserManager.fragment);

}
```

So, what is the fragment that var owill be?  Will it be "my-important-stuff"? Or do I get everything after the hash, "view=my-important-stuff"

I've got a viewStack and the viewStack.selectedChid is equal to "my-important-stuff" and I'm having problems grabbing that string from  var o.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've got it It returns everything after the #.

So, it's: view=my-important-stuff

Thanks,

Laxmidi